# Egorov theorem Stein book page 33

Tags: measure-theory

The proof defines$$E_k^n=\left \{x\in E:|f_j(x)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{n}\forall j>k\right \}.$$Fixing $n$ and letting $k\to \infty$ we have then $E_k^n\to E$.

So for some $k_n$ we have $m\left (E-E_{k_n}^n\right )<2^{-n}$. So we can choose $N$ such that $\sum \limits _{n>N}2^{-n}<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$.

Then it defines$$A_\varepsilon =\bigcap \limits _{n>N}E_{k_n}^n$$this makes$$m(E-A_\varepsilon )<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$$From there it just need to get a closed set in $A_\varepsilon$ to conclude the theorem (the uniform convergence on a closed set which is almost $E$).

Is it really needed to define $ A_\varepsilon =\bigcap \limits _{n>N}E_{k_n}^n$ or should I be able to pick $A_\varepsilon =E_{k_N}^N$ for some specific $N$ depending on $\varepsilon$?

Every time I read the theorem I could not figure out a reason to force me to choose $ A_\varepsilon =\bigcap \limits _{n>N}E_{k_n}^n$. I think all that matters is that $m(E-A_\varepsilon )<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$, but it will still happen choosing (for me) the simpler $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same confusion as you a few hours ago. After some thought, it turns out, the point of taking $\tilde{A}_\epsilon:= \bigcap_{n\geq N} E_{k_n}^n$ is to make sure this set is fixed for the changing value $\delta>0$. If not taking this step and only using the sets $E_{k_n}^n$, you'll need a different value of $n$ for every value of $\delta$. But, for the functions sequence $\{f_n\}$ to satisfy the definition of "uniform convergence", every $f_n$, as well as the limit function $f$, must share a fixed domain, not a changing one. The $E_{k_n}^n$'s can't do that job.

Note, the value $\epsilon$ only regulates how large this subset $A_\epsilon$ should be, in terms of its measure, but it doesn't serve as the gauge of how close function values $f_j(x)$ are to the limit value $f(x)$. That gauge, which is $\delta$, is independent of $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the top of page 34, you will see that the point of defining $A_\epsilon$ in that way is to establish uniform continuity of the $f_j$ on $A_\epsilon$. To do so, they fix an arbitrary $\delta > 0$ (different from the $\epsilon$ you've been using so far) and show that $|f_j(x)-f(x)| < \delta$ for $x \in A_\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $j$. In order for you to be able to do this for any $\delta > 0$, you need that intersection; if you fix $A_\epsilon = E^N_{k_N}$ you may find that $N$ is not large enough for very small choices of $\delta$.